# Looking for public data set with long tailed predictor

Tags: data-transformation

I am looking for some public data set in health science with long tailed predictor and binary outcome. If you happen to see one of them, could you please let me know?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Health care data meeting the specifics of your request may be hard to track down. Individual or household-level health insurance claims data would be ideal for your purposes. Unfortunately, I'm not aware of any public source for that.

Here is an article discussing access to CMS (Medicare) information:

https://insights.riccagroup.com/are-you-taking-advantage-of-free-healthcare-data/

Here are the answers to a Quora.com query about publicly available, large datasets that has a laundry list of options. There may be something in there that will work for you:

https://www.quora.com/Where-can-I-find-large-datasets-open-to-the-public